# How to build DPDK shared libraries?

Tags: dpdk

I am using dpdk-stable-18.11.8 on Centos 7 with gcc compiler.

Dpdk quick start script usertools/dpdk-setup.sh option 15 builds dpdk successfully for environment x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc but builds only static libraries. I want to link dpdk to our own shared (.so) library and therefore need to build dpdk shared libraries.

I have looked at the dpdk documentation but cannot see how to do this.

Is there a 'make' option that I can specify, or do I need to use meson?  What is the correct procedure please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `$RTE_TARGET/.config` the current values `CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=n`. Change the same to `CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=y` and rebuild. You will now find `$RTE_TARGET/lib/` with `*.so`

You can also cross check `$RTE_SDK/devtools/test-build.sh` for `SHARED` to find, the internal logic is `sed -ri 's,(SHARED_LIB=)n,\1y,' $1/.config`